# Qualcomm Atheros AR8172/8176/8178 network UNCLAIMED

Tags: networking, drivers, lenovo

I installed Ubuntu OS. The following is information about the version.

```
root@nithi-Lenovo-G400s:~# uname  -a  
Linux nithi-Lenovo-G400s 3.5.0-23-generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 25 17:15:33 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
root@nithi-Lenovo-G400s:~#
```

This is on Lenovo Laptop model is G400s, WiFi network is working fine, but wired network is not working.

```
root@nithi-Lenovo-G400s:~# lshw -C network  
PCI (sysfs)  
  *-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Atheros Communications Inc.
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:d3500000-d353ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Atheros Communications Inc.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 24:fd:52:4a:b4:ff
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.5.0-23-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.100 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:d3400000-d347ffff memory:bfb00000-bfb0ffff
root@nithi-Lenovo-G400s:~# 
root@nithi-Lenovo-G400s:~# sudo dmidecode -t 1; lspci; lsusb; lsb_release -a; uname -a
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: LENOVO
    Product Name: 20244
    Version: Lenovo G400s
    Serial Number: 3163417401775
    UUID: FED012F9-23BD-E211-A312-2089849B0394
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: LENOVO_MT_20244
    Family: IDEAPAD
```

Would you please advice where i can get drivers for network card and how to configure.

Comment: Please add this information from the terminal: lspci -nn | grep 0200

Comment: please find following are requested information

Comment: Where? Did I miss it? ???

Answer (score 0):

First enter `lspci -nn | grep 0200` and make sure that your drivers is `Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet[1969:10a0]`

The following fix is is only going to work for-

- 1969:1091 - AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet
- 1969:1090 - AR8162 Fast Ethernet
- 1969:10A1 - QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
- 1969:10A0 - QCA8172 Fast Ethernet

adapters. and please make sure that your kernel is 2.6.24 or above. It is technically possible for kernels < 2.6.24 but might take some work. (still worth giving a try!) to check the kernel version type

```
uname -a
```

after that, If they are all neat and right. download `compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u.tar.bz2` file and extract it. go to the extracted directory [ex- `cd Downloads/compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u/`] and type-

```
./scripts/driver-select alx
make
sudo make install
```

reboot the system you are all done :) apparently this type of ethernet adapters are available in lenovo g500s, lenovo g500 series, lenovo g400 series, asus 3rd gen laptops, (you better check before installing)

for more information go to http://www.linuxfoundation.org

Thanks to [Lusus Naturae](http://meinewenigkeit.blogspot.com/2013/08/gentoo-and-atheros-qca8172-fast-ethernet.html). His forum showed me this way. so the rewards goes to him.